# Shortening my Html helper CSS styling

Tags: html, css, helper

I'm creating my first MVC web application (and posting my first question to this forum having read hundreds).  My question is how do I create the form (image is at http://www.flickr.com/photos/82728157@N04/8194924118/in/photostream/lightbox/ ) without such lengthy code (below image).  The model and controller are so laconic thanks to MVC, however, I don't think I really understand how to leverage css and div's in the view.  My formatting requirements are:  1) label and field on same line  2) validation message below each field doesn't increase the spacing between the fields if it displays it's message 3)the distance between the last letter of the label and edge of the input box is constant.

```
<div style="width: 315px; height: 300px; margin: auto auto; text-align:center">
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    <div>
        <fieldset>
          <div class="logon-label" style="float:left; width: 110px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClientId)
          </div>
          <div style="float:left; width: 110px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClientId, new { @class = "logon-field" })
         </div>
          <div style="clear:both; height:15px">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ClientId,null, new {@class="logon-validation"})
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both"></div>

          <div class="logon-label" style="float:left; width: 110px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
          </div>
          <div style="float:left; width: 110px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "logon-field" })
         </div>
          <div style="clear:both; height:15px">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName,null, new {@class="logon-validation"})
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both"></div>
          <div class="logon-label" style="float:left; width: 110px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
          </div>
          <div style="float:left; width: 110px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "logon-field" })
         </div>
          <div style="clear:both; height:15px">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password,null, new {@class="logon-validation"})
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both"></div>

         <p>
             <input type="submit" style="width: 150px; font-size:large" value="Login"  />
         </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having CSS definitions inline mixed up with `HTML`, `JS` etc is not good and easy way. I would recommend you to read about some of existing `CSS frameworks`. I personally prefer `Twitter Bootstrap CSS Framework`. It is easy to understand and to use as well.

Bootstrap link: [http:///twitter.github.com/bootstrap/](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Example (simple form with `Twitter Bootstrap CSS Framework`) [here](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/example-horizontal-form-with-twitter-bootstrap.html).

Comment: Salih,  Thanks also for taking the time to answer.  Sounds like the way I mix in-line CSS with class derived CSS is not good form.  I did this since the textboxfor would not take a CSS class as an argument.  By wrapping it in a div that had a class... the textbox inherited it.  Given how steep the learning curve is thus far... I don't think I'm game yet for learning another framework (or should I)?

Comment: Hello; you are very welcome. Yes, I think you should definitely learn some CSS Framework; it will make your life much easier (it did mine). Twitter Bootstrap has good documentation. The best part of using CSS Framework is that it has been setup to work on many different platforms (mobile devices, IE, Firefox etc). Thousands of users are reporting issues; participating in improvements etc... Now if you find my answer useful please consider marking it as good to go so the other users could find it easier. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Good place to start: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples (few complete templates). It depends on your CSS knowledge (mine was ... average when started using Twitter Bootstrap); it took me 30 minutes to figure it out :-) Just read docs provided. I've also tried Blueprint CSS, jQuery UI etc. They are all good. You can google for CSS reviews online. I love this one :-) It is time saving...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some application automatically generating the HTML. If you write it yourself, it would be much easier for you.

In this case I would prefer using table, but div blocks isn't wrong too. Anyway I think your code is unnecessary complicated.

Just an example for you how CSS works - remove `style="..."` attribute everywhere you have `class="logon-label"` and copy `<style>...</style>` code below, it should render in the exact same way. Another example [here](http://jsbin.com/akuwil/1/edit).

```
<style>
.logon-label {
  float:left; 
  width: 110px; 
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
</style>
...
<div class="logon-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClientId)
</div>
...
```

More about CSS [click here](http://w3schools.com/css/).

Comment: Erik,  thanks for the quick reply :)  I actually hand wrote all of the above code in my novice way after reading CSS tutorials.   I tried the simpler idea you posted as my first idea... however, to have everything align correctly, I seem to need a left floated div of a fixed width and within that have a right floated label.  I just don't know how to do it more eloquently.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/inihor/1/edit here it is, enjoy. Sorry that I thought you're using app to write your code, but it looks very complicated to be human written. :)

Comment: Erik,  Thanks again for taking time to answer.  I definitely feel better knowing that for experienced programmers like you, lots of lines are still needed to layout even a simple login boxk.  I'll try to move my inline style code to the CSS stylesheet and see if I can get my model-bound fields to format right.  I failed the first time which is why I wrapped them in the divs like I did.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

```css
<style>
  .intro {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
     <body>
       <div class="intro">
       <form name="frm" action="" method="post">
         Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
         password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="btn" value="ok"><br>
        </form>
         </div>
       </body>
     </head>
  </html>
```

##